# While replication my view settings are not synchronizing

Tags: lotus-notes, database-replication

I am having replica copy in local. I changed the design like color, font, view style {grid, alter color and line spacing}. But the changes in form and other design elements have changed except view. Please tell why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the view is a regular "Shared" view, not marked as "Shared, private on first use".

Hmmm.... I don't actually see a way to check that in any properties dialog in Domino Designer.  You can only set the type when creating the view. The only clue would be the key icon that appears next to the view name when looking at the list of views.

Comment: Yes, the only way you can tell if a view is "shared, private on first use" (SPoFU) is in the list of views. It will be listed with an icon to the far left that has a key with the number 1 floating above it. Private views (like the ones created from those) show the key, but no number. When someone using a Designer client has a view created from a SPoFU, it will list the SPoFU as well as the private view created from it.